# Span with overflow: hidden; doesn't show up in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

For some reason it floats below the place it should actually be.

**Example on Firefox:**

[image]

**Example on Chrome:**

[image]

- Demo: http://jvnknvlgl.github.io/oxygen-template
- Source: http://github.com/jvnknvlgl/oxygen-template

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <span><a class="main-current" href="index.html">Home</a></span>
  <span><a class="main" href="page-1/sub-1.html">Subpages</a></span>
  <span><a class="main" href="page-2.html">Multi-column</a></span>

  <! The span it's about >
  <span class="credits"><a class="credits" target="_blank" href="http://github.com/jvnknvlgl/oxygen-template">Oxygen by jvnknvlgl</a></span>

</nav>
```

CSS:

```
span {
  line-height: 56px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

span.credits {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

nav {
  max-width: 800px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help!

Comment: You put wrong image first is of firefox and second is of chrome.

Comment: It seems that it is an [old bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=488725) so as suggested changing white-space would be the best solution.

Comment: @ketan it seems the one who edited my question messed that up. Let me edit it, thanks.

Comment: @CrissLion yes, but that removes all other items from the navigation bar if you resize the browser window or view it on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nav {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

then have a media query for when your navigation links start to disapear and revert back to:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    nav {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Like I told in the comments below Ketan's answer: that fixes my issue, yes, but it removes all other links on the navigation bar if you resize the page or view it on mobile.

Comment: Can I ask what you expect the navigation bar to do when it gets to mobile? Should it just stay the same with the credits removed or are you going to change it in to a dropbar etc?

Comment: I expect the credits to go away and the nav to become horizontally scrollable to show all of the other spans. This works on Chrome, but for some reason it doesn't on Firefox.

Comment: Updated my answer to give the effect you are looking for... you may need to change the width on the query a bit

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. I suppose I have to change the the query width when I add more spans?

Comment: Yeah Just add in all your spans, then resize in the browser and see when it breaks (or spans disapear) then note that width and add 10px on for good measure

Answer (score 3):

Just remove

```
nav {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Will solved your issue.

Comment: That fixes my issue, yes, but it removes all other links on the navigation bar if you resize the page or view it on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Remove

```
nav {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Like I told in the comments below Ketan's answer: that fixes my issue, yes, but it removes all other links on the navigation bar if you resize the page or view it on mobile.